# File creation fails because i cant add the name

Tags: c++, file

I have created a c++ program that will make a text file on the desktop of the user. My only problem is, that I need to add the name of the file. In this case, I tried to add it in the string seen below named "filename". I know that the error is that I cant use the operator "+" in the string to add the name of the file. Does anyone have another way of doing this?
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ShlObj.h>
using namespace std;
wstring GetUserDesktopPath()
{
    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &path);
    if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
        wprintf_s(L"Path:  %ls\n", path);
    }
    
    
    
    return path;
}
int main()
{   
    wstring currentDesktop = GetUserDesktopPath();
    Sleep(4000);
    string filename = currentDesktop + "/suprise.txt";
    ofstream myfile(filename);
    if (myfile.is_open() == false) {
        cout << "File creation failed";
        return 0;
    }
    myfile << "I like cake";
    myfile.close();


    return 0;
   
}
```

Comment: Create wide string literals with an `L` prefix - `L"like this"`.

Comment: so like this: wstring = L"/suprise.txt"

Comment: You want to use `filename`, not `currentDesktop` in the stream constructor, I think...

Comment: @ravnsgaard yes, sorry about that, did some minor changes to the code before posting this, and forgot to fix that.

Comment: *"I know that the error is that I cant use the operator '+' in the string to add the name of the file."* -- if you know what the error is, then you don't need to ask us. If you don't know what the error is, you should provide the error message verbatim, copy-pasted as text. Don't make us rely on your (incorrect) interpretation of the message.

Comment: @CPPNEWBIE Instead of complaining, you could edit your question to make it better. For example, despite acknowledging that `myfile(currentDesktop)` is wrong you still have not fixed it in your question. The more errors you leave in your question, the harder it is to tell which of your mistakes you are asking about. That makes it harder both for others to provide answers and for others to benefit from your contribution (when they have the same issue in the future).

Comment: Forgot to add: this is where adding the error message comes in. If your question had the error message, people answering would know which error to focus on. If your question had the error message as text, people with the same issue would be able to search for that error message and find this post. Quick win without you needing to be aware of every error.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, but if there were an error message I would have included it. 
But there wasn't. Because I made a human error and not a code error.

Comment: @CPPNEWBIE In that caste, your question might be poorly worded as it reads to me like there was an error while compiling. In any event, in the absence of an error message, you should include the expected and actual results that demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to @molbdnilo In the comments, I fixed the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <ShlObj.h>
    using namespace std;
    wstring GetUserDesktopPath()
    {
        PWSTR path = NULL;
        HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &path);
        if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
            wprintf_s(L"Path:  %ls\n", path);
        }
        
        
        
        return path;
    }
    int main()
    {   
        wstring currentDesktop = GetUserDesktopPath();
        Sleep(4000);
        wstring lastname = L"/suprise.txt";
        wstring filename = currentDesktop + lastname;
        ofstream myfile(filename);
        if (myfile.is_open() == false) {
            cout << "File creation failed";
            return 0;
        }
        myfile << "I like cake";
        myfile.close();
    
    
        return 0;
       
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI, if you are going to combine path segments like this, it would be better to use an API like [`PathCombine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew) or [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) instead.  Let them deal with the folder/file separators for you.

Comment: okay, thank you! I will definitely look into that :)